# Mysql select main table value for where and join table for result

Tags: php, mysql, join

Hello I would like to be able to select value from the main table `'properties'` to be used in the where clause and then for the actual query to select value from the joined table. Here is my DB structure.

table properties:

```
id | title | property_type | city | sector | bedrooms
-----------------------------------------------------
1  | hotel | 7             | 4    | 1      | three
-----------------------------------------------------


table city

id | cityname |
---------------
2  | Plovdiv  |
---------------

table sector

id | sectorname|
---------------
2  | Trakia    |
----------------

table property_typ 


etc.
```

So here is the actual query on which I am receiving error:

```
$query= "SELECT 
   P.id,P.price
  ,P.contract,P.property_type
  ,P.sector,P.title
  ,P.address,P.bedrooms
  ,P.bathrooms,P.price
  ,P.m2,P.text_english
  ,P.photo_01,P.utilities
  ,P.google_maps,P.date
  ,CT.id,CT.english_text
  ,PT.id,PT.english
  ,C.cityname,S.sectorname
  ,S.id,O.ownername
  ,O.phone_one,O.phone_two
  ,O.email,O.notes
FROM properties P
   JOIN contract CT ON CT.id = P.contract
   JOIN property_type PT ON PT.id = P.property_type
   JOIN city C ON C.id = P.city
   JOIN sector S ON S.id = P.sector
   JOIN owner O ON O.id = P.owner 
FROM properties 
WHERE P.sector = 2";
```

Any help letting me this if this can be achieved will be very welcome.

> ERROR: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM properties WHERE P.sector = 2; LIMIT 0, 30' at line 43' in E:\xampp\htdocs\dolche\admin\class\pagination.php:451 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\dolche\admin\class\pagination.php(451): PDOStatement->execute() #1 E:\xampp\htdocs\dolche\admin\search.php(191): pagination->execute() #2 {main} thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\dolche\admin\class\pagination.php on line 451

Comment: _"So here is the actual query on which I am receiving error:"_ And what is the error?

Comment: The syntax error pretty much states the problem, you have an additional `FROM properties` just before your `WHERE`. Remove it and you should be OK.

Comment: The question is edited and the error message is added.

Comment: Thanks I was to make sure that the query is working, it is now, the problem which I am facing now is different one. which I will probably post in another question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `FROM properties` before the `WHERE` clause:

```
JOIN owner O
ON O.id = P.owner WHERE P.sector = 2";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using FROM property for multiple times, remove **from-2** of the two indicated below.

```
$query= "SELECT 
   P.id
  ,P.price
  .
  .
  ,O.email
  ,O.notes

FROM properties P
 ^from-1
JOIN contract CT
  ON CT.id = P.contract
  .
  .
JOIN owner O
  ON O.id = P.owner FROM properties WHERE P.sector = 2";
                     ^from-2
```